# Is there a way to change the icon colors and time color to black in windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

[image: screenshot]

I want these icons and the text to be colored black. Switching to light mode makes the time black, but I don't want to use light mode. Same thing with high contrast mode. Any third party tool is also appreciated, but I'd prefer if I didn't use them.

Comment: I don't think this is natively possible. I don't even think this ever was possible. You basically need a light shade of color for the text to become black, or a dark shaded color for the text to become white. Only thing that will work is to use high contrast, but that's ugly, you probably don't want that anyway. That leaves the only option, third party programs that skin your OS, such as Stardock and Window Blinds. Maybe there's a taskbar replacement that has this.